# Desktop settings lost after unclean shutdown

Tags: gnome, package-management, dpkg

My laptop restarted because the battery ran out of juice. Now the Gnome settings are gone. The panels are looking very bad. I am hearing sounds that were not there before restart. Menus are not appearing nor are the launchers that I added to the panel. How do I get my previous settings back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was updating my system using `apt-get update` and apparently it had not finished when the system restarted. I just tried installing meld using `apt-get install meld`

Then I got a message that I need to correct some error using command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` after that when I restarted my system everything was back to normal.

This is similar to the same solution when there is an error while downloading: [dpkg interrupted error while downloading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17824/dpkg-error-while-downloading)

Comment: @Jorge Castro, I think you dont get the point here. the commad "sudo dpkg --configure -a" solved my problem. I dont know how or why but after this command when I restarted the system my settings were back

Comment: oh, I see, this is actually almost a dupe, I'll link it up and then we can clean up these comments.

Comment: Why? according to http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/111/ought-one-to-answer-ones-own-question, his own answer should be accepted.

Comment: @danizmax I think he should accept his own answer, I just added a link to a similar problem (hence the "almost a dupe") for reference. (sorry, don't mean to be so confusing, I need caffeine!)

Comment: Haha according to your big reputations you do :P